# how can I print JSON in dart?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

This is my JSON file, so if I want to print `percent_change_1h` what is the **dart** code for it?

```
    {
        "data": [
           {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Bitcoin",
                "symbol": "BTC",
                "slug": "bitcoin",
                "cmc_rank": 5,
                "num_market_pairs": 500,
                "circulating_supply": 16950100,
                "total_supply": 16950100,
                "max_supply": 21000000,
                "last_updated": "2018-06-02T22:51:28.209Z",
                "date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                "tags": [
                "mineable"
                ],
                "platform": null,
                "quote": {
                   "USD": {
                       "price": 9283.92,
                       "volume_24h": 7155680000,
                       "percent_change_1h": -0.152774,
                       "percent_change_24h": 0.518894,
                       "percent_change_7d": 0.986573,
                       "market_cap": 158055024432,
                       "last_updated": "2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z"
                    },
                    "BTC": {
                       "price": 1,
                       "volume_24h": 772012,
                       "percent_change_1h": 0,
                       "percent_change_24h": 0,
                       "percent_change_7d": 0,
                       "market_cap": 17024600,
                       "last_updated": "2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z"
                    }
                }
           },
        ],
    }
```

This is the code

```
Future getCurrencies() async {
    String cryptoUrl = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest";

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(cryptoUrl),
     headers: {
       'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'MY-API',
       "Accept": "application/json",
     });

    return jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
}
```

And this is the stacktrace
#0 and #1 is where I'm printing percent_change_1h

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _HomePageState._getListItemUI (package:crypto_example/home_page.dart:78:44)
#1      _HomePageState._cryptoWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:crypto_example/home_page.dart:49:18)
#2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:455:22)
#3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1213:28)
#4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1226:55)
...
```

This is the code i use for print
`Text(currency['percent_change_1h']`

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: @julemand101 I added it in my question

Comment: Can you add the full error message including stacktrace?

Comment: Ok, your problem is that you are trying to access `percent_change_1h` from `data` but `percent_change_1h` is inside `USD` and `BTC` which are inside `quote`. You need to browse through the parsed JSON structure to find your value.

Comment: can you tell me how can i do that? i have no idea how to browse

Comment: You just need to do: `return jsonDecode(response.body)['data'][0]['quote']['USD']['percent_change_1h'];` . As you can see, we are going through the structure map by map until we gets the value we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go through the JSON structure after you have parsed it. In your case it is going to look something like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  print(jsonDecode(jsonString)['data'][0]['quote']['USD']['percent_change_1h']);
  // -0.152774

  print(jsonDecode(jsonString)['data'][0]['quote']['BTC']['percent_change_1h']);
  // 0
}

const jsonString = '''
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "slug": "bitcoin",
      "cmc_rank": 5,
      "num_market_pairs": 500,
      "circulating_supply": 16950100,
      "total_supply": 16950100,
      "max_supply": 21000000,
      "last_updated": "2018-06-02T22:51:28.209Z",
      "date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "tags": [
        "mineable"
      ],
      "platform": null,
      "quote": {
        "USD": {
          "price": 9283.92,
          "volume_24h": 7155680000,
          "percent_change_1h": -0.152774,
          "percent_change_24h": 0.518894,
          "percent_change_7d": 0.986573,
          "market_cap": 158055024432,
          "last_updated": "2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z"
        },
        "BTC": {
          "price": 1,
          "volume_24h": 772012,
          "percent_change_1h": 0,
          "percent_change_24h": 0,
          "percent_change_7d": 0,
          "market_cap": 17024600,
          "last_updated": "2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}    
''';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart';

typedef JMap = Map<String, dynamic>;
typedef JList = List<dynamic>;

class CoinMarketCap {
  static const _apiKey = '1234567890';
  static const _base = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency';
  static FutureOr<void> showListingLatest() async {
    stdout.write('Fetching info... ');
    late final JList data;
    await HttpReqService.getJson<JMap>(
      '$_base/listings/latest', 
      headers: {'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': _apiKey}
    )
    .then((response) => data = response?['data'] ?? [])
    .whenComplete(() {
      print('done.\n');
      data.forEach((m) { 
        (m['quote'] as JMap).forEach((key, value) => print('$key -> ${value['percent_change_1h']}'));
      });
    });
  }
}
void main(List<String> args) async {
  await CoinMarketCap.showListingLatest();
  print('\nJob done!');
}
```

Result:

```
Fetching info... done.

USD -> -0.25887504
USD -> -0.65608893
USD -> 0.0063961
USD -> -0.35961035
USD -> -0.31282692
....
USD -> -0.5774129
USD -> -0.21221476
USD -> -1.72516994
USD -> -0.67800762
USD -> 0.03411096

Job done!
```